# Can I log flight time in unregistered helicopters?

Tags: flight-training, helicopter, logging

Is there a way to log my flight hours from these flights?

During a time I was in middle east I had an opportunity to fly Astar for more than 200+ hours with multi experience majors as Long line, Rabbling, Mountain Operation, NVG, ... etc, however I'm not a licenced pilot but I have a good experience on Astar,

Now I decided to get use of that experience and put all the effort into some licenced actions but I have a hard time to find how to count my flight hours or if anything can be done with those hours.

I will appreciate all your help.

Cheers
Bravo

Comment: It would help if you were specific about what country you are attempting to get your license in, and what license specifically you are wanting to acquire.

Comment: It may help though to note that many ICAO compliant countries, unless you are under instruction of a flight instructor or you are a licensed pilot, you cannot log time towards a license or rating.

Comment: Even if you can't log the hours, you still have the experience that should make formal training a lot easier/quicker/cheaper -- assuming you don't have any bad habits to fix.

Comment: You may edit the question so that it is clear what you are asking for without the need to read the entire question. When reading the title, it should be obvious what you are asking for about flight time on unregister helicopter. Moreover, you should be more direct when you ask your question (e.g. "I'm an experience pilot and i want to know...." and then your story "i spend time in middle east..." )

Comment: I'm confused. You title says "unregistered helicopter" which indicates to me that it wasn't registered with the appropriate authorities in the country you were flying in, then your question says that you are not a licensed pilot. Are both of these statements true? I'm not sure if flying an unregistered aircraft has any impact on your ability to log time, but that might be an important bit of information to clarify.

Comment: If you're in the US, [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30932/62) might be helpful. It would be good to know which country you want to train in but the comments by others are almost certainly correct: if you didn't fly with a certified instructor who signed your logbook for the flights, then they can't be used towards a license.